# Extending My namespace in VB.NET/WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

In Windows Forms, I have My namespace classes extended with some useful methods. For example:

```
Namespace My
    Partial Friend Class MyComputer
        Public Function IsPortAvailable(ByVal port As Integer) As Boolean
        ...
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

And then using:
`My.Computer.IsPortAvailable(12345)`
Unfortunately this does not work in WPF application (VS2013 Community). Any solution to this except creating new class/module in My namespace?

Comment: What specifically doesn't work? Can you show us a sample of your WPF consuming code please?

Comment: If you put code above into empty class file and compile, IsPortAvailable method is not available via My.Computer class. In other words, there is no My.Computer.IsPortAvailable method in WPF project, but there is in Windows Forms project.

Comment: If you insist on doing it this way then you'll have to use `Dim hasPort = New My.MyComputer().IsPortAvailable(12345)`

Comment: Public Class Form1 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    MsgBox(My.Computer.IsPortAvailable(12345))
    End Sub
    End Class
    Namespace My
    Partial Friend Class MyComputer
    Public Function IsPortAvailable(ByVal port As Integer) As Boolean
    Return False
    End Function
    End Class
    End Namespace

Comment: Stop blabbering nonsense a try code above in empty Windows Forms project (Framework 4.0, Visual Studio Community 2013).